# How to send Server response in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have tried of the following in app controller's before filter, didn't seem work out

```
$this->response->statusCode(404);
```

or

```
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Unauthorized', true, 404);
header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
```

or

```
throw new NotFoundException();
```

If I debug the response, the status is shown as 404, but HTTP Status checker always returns 200 I don't know why

Found the solutions

```
if (!function_exists('http_response_code'))
{
    function http_response_code($newcode = NULL)
    {
        static $code = 200;
        if($newcode !== NULL)
        {
            header('X-PHP-Response-Code: '.$newcode, true, $newcode);
            if(!headers_sent())
                $code = $newcode;
        }       
        return $code;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Comment: well....I'm using 1.3 and 2.4 for two different projects and I wanted this on both so I didn't mentioned the version...but thanks anyways

Comment: There are huge differences between those. The answer should probably be focusing on 2.x.

Comment: Yes, there is....but the project was done on the previous version almost impossible to update to the new one, that would be equal to doing the whole project completely. That's why I wanted a solution that would suit for the both, and since the above answer is based on the php it doesn't depend on the whatever cakephp version you are using.

Comment: Using exceptions or `$this->response` it very much does so, though.

Comment: I tried them out too, but didn't work, I don't know why....the checker always return 200, the header 404 is not sent